# Adding additional padding with Width="Auto"

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a Listview with multiple GridViewColumns, I am using Width="Auto" for each of the columns, this ensures that the columns are sized according to their largest element.

I want to add additional breathing space for each column header, something along the lines of: 
Width = "Auto" + 30

I have tried setting Margins and padding however this results in the Column text heading being cut off prematurely when resized.
Any ideas on how I can achieve this ?

My GridViewColumn currently ?

```
<GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
        <GridViewColumn.Header>
            <GridViewColumnHeader HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                  Content="{x:Static resources:Resources.TableHeadingDescription}" 
                                  SizeChanged="Description_Column_SizeChanged">
            </GridViewColumnHeader>
        </GridViewColumn.Header>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Name="DescriptionTextBlock" 
                       Text="{Binding Description}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_GridEntries_Style}"
                       Margin="{Binding HierarchyLevel, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource HierarchyToMarginConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

add ContentTemplate to GridViewColumnHeader, and in template set some Margin on element

```
<GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
    <GridViewColumn.Header>
        <GridViewColumnHeader HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                              Content="{x:Static resources:Resources.TableHeadingDescription}" 
                              SizeChanged="Description_Column_SizeChanged">
            <GridViewColumnHeader.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Margin="30,0" Content="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumnHeader.ContentTemplate>
        </GridViewColumnHeader>
    </GridViewColumn.Header>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Name="DescriptionTextBlock" 
                   Text="{Binding Description}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_GridEntries_Style}"
                   Margin="{Binding HierarchyLevel, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource HierarchyToMarginConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn>
```