# How can i add padding to a gridviews 'Auto' width

Tags: c#, wpf

My question is similar to [Adding additional padding with Width="Auto"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094674/adding-additional-padding-with-width-auto) but that question has no answers.

I have a grid that im sizing all columns using `Auto`, which works best in most of my use cases. However sometimes leaving little to no breathing room is not ideal (or it just looks ugly).

Is it possible to set my width to something similar to `Auto + 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change HeaderTemplate and add Margin on template element:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="TableHeadingDescription">
    <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

or use simple template with Label without Margin because Label happens to have `5` Padding and can display arbitrary Content, not only strings:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="TableHeadingDescription">
    <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```